# Excessive padding between Cardviews in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am having difficulty reducing padding between Cards in RecyclerView

[Padding Issue Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzPS3.jpg)

The screenshots above were taken in Developer Mode's "Show Layout Bounds" option so the issue appears to be with the padding.

When the CardView is removed it returns to normal padding, although I would not make this change because I want CardView

I manually added negative and zero paddings which didn't work.

I also added `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` which didn't work either.

My Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
       >

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Ayoub"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical|fill_horizontal"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try changing your scaletype of the imageview

Answer (score 0):

**Change this :**

```
android:layout_height="225dp"
```

**to :**

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `RelativeLayout` should wrap_content not match_parent